# Write the following statements in if then form? Are my answers correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

(a) It is necessary that x is irrational for 1/x to be irrational.

my answer: If 1/x is irrational then it is necessary that x is irrational.

(b) I get an A in my English class only if I get an A on the final.

my answer: If I get an A in my English class then I got an A on the final

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "necessary" in the if-then form. The first can just be "if $1/x$ is irrational then $x$ is irrational".

The second one is right (except perhaps for the change in tense).

Comment: So you think the second would should maybe be "If I got an A on the final then I get an A in my English class."?

Comment: @gnollwarden With the original sentence as written, both verbs should stay present tense. Of course writing English this way is a bit weird; more likely we would say "If I get an A on the final then I will get an A in the class" or something like this.